# Embed words into array. Boolean issue.

Tags: c, arrays, boolean

Okay so ive been trying to make a Word Search game and need to embed words into a grid. The words cant overlap or go off the edges.

Ive managed to generate a grid roughly like:

```
           .........X
           .........X
           .........X
           .........X
           .........X
           .........X
           xxxxxxxxxx
```

Im trying to make is so that if the play in the array is a ".", then the character from my word can replace the dot, and if its not a dot, then it breaks the loop.

However if i use the word dog and set my array to place 7, im getting:

```
            .......DOG
            .........X
            .........X
            .........X etc...
```

Here is my code for the function that im using to embed words in horizontally.

```
    int horizontal(char *myArray, char * word)
    {
         int length = strlen(word);
         int rand = 17;//rand_num_gen();
         printf("i = %d\n", rand);
         int a;
         int lettercount = 0;

         for(a=0; a < (length); a++)
         {
               if(myArray[rand] = '.')
               {
                  myArray[rand] = word[a];
                  rand++; 
                  lettercount++;
               }
               else
               {
                  break;
               }
         }
         printf("lettercount = %d\n", lettercount);
         printf("length = %d\n", length);
         int success = 0;
         if(lettercount == length)
         {
              success = 1;     
         } 
         return success; 

    }
```

Can anyone point out where im going wrong and possibly give me something that would work?

Comment: I'm not going to try to understand your code, but `if(myArray[rand] = '.')` should probably be `if(myArray[rand] == '.')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(myArray[rand] = '.')
```

This line assigns the value of `myArray[rand]` to be `'.'`. If, as I expect, you are looking to compare values, you want the `==` operator.

Comment: Ahh i have not idea how i could of overlooked that! Thank you! :)

Comment: Your clicking on the green check mark next to the answer is all the thanks I need :)

Comment: Just need to wait 3 mins apparently :)